# Jenkins job finishes late than actual execution time

Tags: jenkins

I'm running a freestyle jenkins job which executes cucumber test cases on a windows slave machine. The actual execution completed in 17:23 mins but the jenkins job takes overall 42 mins to finish.

what is causing this delay?

command used to execute `mvn clean test`

```
[ERROR] Tests run: 153, Failures: 14, Errors: 14, Skipped: 114
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] **Total time: 17:23 min**
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-10-11T17:05:23+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 10M/25M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.0:test (default-test) on project com.lloyds.IPP: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to C:\Jenkins\workspace\IPP-BDD-Sanity-Pack\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date]-jvmRun[N].dump, [date].dumpstream and [date]-jvmRun[N].dumpstream.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
```

Comment: This would probably be a better question for StackOverflow or DevOps, see https://meta.superuser.com/questions/13805/should-we-do-something-about-the-high-number-of-jenkins-questions-with-no-votes

Answer (score 0):

Time spent waiting in the queue or not running in an executor slot (i.e. steps that run outside of a `node` or `agent` block) should not count towards the total execution time.

Answer (score 0):

Where do you get the 42 mins from ?

You should see in the Jenkins build log under "Status", a section that looks like:

> This run spent:
>
> - 9 min 33 sec waiting;
> - 9 min 13 sec build duration;
> - 18 min total from scheduled to completion.

Also, that time is only for the maven build step. clean step has a separate time. So do the Jenkins SCM steps, pre- and post-build steps; they add to the total.

We have a job that takes 20 mins to download the repo and only a few minutes to execute the steps.